# Javascript confirmation and jquery fadein not responding

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Each time someone click the unregister button, there is a confirmation dialog, but when I click there isn't any respond. I also try to make a jquery effect by giving the fadein effect when the pade loaded, but there isn't any response also. I save the page ini .php extension.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("*").fadeIn(4000);
    });
    function confirm() {
      var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to register?")
      if (answer){
        window.location = "unregister.php";
      }
      else{
        alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
      }
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post">
    <a href="logout.php"><button>Logout</button></a>

      <a href="form.php"><button>Add New record</button></a>
      <a href="register.php"><button>Edit Profile</button></a>
      <input type="button" onClick="confirm()" value="Unregister">
      </form>
     </p>
     ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.confirm) is a javascript function, so try changing following:

```
<input type="button" onClick="confirm()" value="Unregister">
```

to

```
<input type="button" onClick="return ask_confirm();" value="Unregister">
```

And

```
function ask_confirm() {
      var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to register?")
      if (answer){
        window.location = "unregister.php";
      }
      else{
        alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sudhir is correct about the confirm function.

The reason your fadeIn does nothing is because it only effects elements that are hidden.

If you really wish to fade the entire page in you need to add:`$("*").hide();` before you call fadeIn.

Edit: Note, most people dislike using `$("*")` as it will literally select everything which can cause problems. For example, when I tested hiding everything then using fadeIn, it made all my progress bars and loading gifs visible.

A better solution would be:

```
$("html").hide();
$("html").fadeIn(4000);
```

This way the page will look exactly how it should, without showing things you wish to remain hidden.

Answer (score 0):

your function confirm has to return true or false

```
function confirm() {
  var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to register?")
  if (answer){
    window.location = "unregister.php";
    return true;
  }
  else{
    alert("Thanks for sticking around!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "http:" prefix:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: No, this isn't a must https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=zh-TW#jquery